# Dynamically added elements have no spacing between them

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have the following template in my markup.

```html
<template id="unsequenced-template">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary railcar"></button>
</template>
```

And then I insert it into my DOM something like this.

```js
// Inserts a railcar in the unsequenced list before the specified target
function addSequenced(railcar, $target) {
    var $clone = $($('#unsequenced-template').html());
    $clone.attr('data-id', railcar.id);
    $clone.text(railcar.number);
    $clone.insertBefore($target);
    modified = true;
}
```

This works, but there is zero spacing between buttons inserted this way. I even tried first appending a space to the `$clone` but it has no effect. I also tried adding whitespace in the template, but that had no effect either.

Some buttons are added on start. They are one per line, and those show a space between buttons. But how can I show spaces between the buttons inserted using JavaScript?

Comment: Why not style them with a `margin-right` or something?

Comment: @Pointy: Yes, I will do that if I need to. But the ones added when the page loads don't need that. So I'm just trying to understand why those added with JavaScript do.

Comment: Well what makes you think that there *should* be spacing? Elements right next to each other do not have implicit spacing.

Comment: Note that if you have elements in the original HTML separated by newlines, the newlines are spaces.

Comment: Why `var $clone = $($('#unsequenced-template').html());` instead of https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: @Pointy: I don't want them to be right next to each other.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Yeah, maybe that's better.

Comment: This is something that should be solved with CSS not JavaScript.

Comment: But when you `.insertBefore()` you're putting a new element immediately adjacent to an existing element. There will be no text nodes between them, because why would there be?

Comment: @Pointy: As I explained, there is whitespace in the template. Also, I described trying to add whitespace to the clone.

Comment: In HTML you probably have buttons each in its own line, basically making it pseudo-wise: `<button>\n<button>\n<button>` but when using append in JS / jQuery you basically get `<button><button><button>`  so I think that  you're basically asking why a newline in HTML results in a whitespace in the resulting HTML - which is indeed your answer.

Comment: @gre_gor: If I add a right margin, then the dynamically added content does not match the static content. The static content has whitespace and the right margin appears to get added in addition to the whitespace.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan: Yes, I get that. But adding newlines to the template doesn't solve it. And, as explained, adding whitespace to the clone doesn't seem to either.

Comment: Whitespace in the template is probably going to be ignored when you get the `.innerHTML` content (via jQuery `.html()`).

Comment: @Pointy: I changed it to `.clone()`, as suggested above, but that seemed the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a flexbox to collapse all the whitespace and then add a gap.

```
#btn-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.2em;
}
```

```js
function addSequenced(railcar, $target) {
    var $clone = $($('#unsequenced-template').html());
    $clone.attr('data-id', railcar.id);
    $clone.text(railcar.number);
    $clone.insertBefore($target);
    modified = true;
}

let num = 4;
$("#add-btn").on("click", function(e) {
  addSequenced({
    id: num,
    number: num,
  }, $(this));
  num++;
});
```

```css
#btn-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  gap: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<template id="unsequenced-template">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary railcar"></button>
</template>
<div id="btn-container">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary railcar">1</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary railcar">2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary railcar">3</button>
  <button id="add-btn" type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Add</button>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks great. But I need it to word wrap if there's more buttons that can fit on a line. This gives it a horizontal scroll bar.

Comment: @JonathanWood Then add `flex-wrap: wrap;`.

Comment: Yes, that seems good. Going to play around with it a bit more. Thanks.